# Numpy: Creating a Vector through Array Comparison is NOT working

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

As shown in the IPython (Python 3) snapshot below I expect to see an array of Boolean values printed in the end. However, I see ONLY 1 Boolean value returned.

1. Unable to identify why?
2. What does the character 'b' before every
   value in the first print statement denote? Am I using the wrong
   dtype=numpy.string_ in my numpy.getfromtxt() command?

[image: Numpy Boolean Value]

Comment: What is the output of `world_alcohol.dtype` and `world_alcohol.shape`?

Comment: @AmiTavory - Modified the image to include the 2 results you wanted above.

Comment: Well, my guess about the "b"s is that you're using Python3 (it looks that way from the `print` also), and it's telling you that these are bytes, not strings (i.e., not unicode). As to the first point, I'm stumped. Just out of curiosity, I'd try to write "... == b'1984', but I can't say that I understand the first point. Sorry.

Comment: That's amazing: the following your recommended change did it: years_1984 = world_alcohol[:,3] == b'"1984"'

Comment: @AmiTavory, please post your solution as an Answer so that I can UpVote it. Thanks.

Comment: :-) <padding padding>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has the distinction between unicode strings and ASCII bytes. In Python3, the default is that "strings" are unicode.

The **b** prefixing the "strings", indicate that the interpreter considers these to be bytes.

For the comparison, you need to compare it to bytes as well, i.e.,

```
... == b"1984"
```

and then numpy will understand that it should perform broadcasting on same-type elements.

Comment: Modify the above comment to include double quotes: == b'"1984"'

Comment: There's a need for a Single Quote: == b'"1984"'