# Numpy: Unable to read float data from file

Tags: python, numpy

I'm unable to convert Strings to Float using Numpy (Python 3):

It turns out that in Python3, the default is that "strings" are unicode. The b prefixing the "strings", indicate that the interpreter considers these to be bytes.

Reference: [Numpy: Creating a Vector through Array Comparison is NOT working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106041/numpy-creating-a-vector-through-array-comparison-is-not-working)

Link to physical file: http://www.filedropper.com/recordedalcoholpercapitaconsumption19801999

What I have tried:

```
import numpy
file = "/home/ds/notebooks/data/fivethirtyeight_data/who/ \   
Recorded_Alcohol_Per_Capita_Consumption_1980_1999.csv"
world_alcohol = numpy.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=",", dtype=numpy.string_, skip_header=1)
print(world_alcohol)
print(world_alcohol.astype(float))
```

for :

```
array([[b'"1.0"',..., b'"2.0"'],
   [b'"3.0"',..., b'"3.0"']], 
  dtype='|S5')


ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"1.0"'
```

Comment: put text instead of image.

Comment: Problem can be because you have text with extra quotation marks - you have text `"0.10"` instead of text `0.10`.

Comment: Have you tried `world_alcohol = numpy.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=",", dtype=numpy.float, skip_header=1)` ?

Comment: @B.M. use of dtype=numpy.float results in [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that your data have trailing `"`; You can use converters option to strip them :

```
def converter(x): return float(x.decode().strip('"')) # converter(b'"23"') ->23.0
alc=numpy.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=",",skip_header=1,\
converters={n:converter for n in range(12)})
```

**EDIT**

The problem is that it's not a homogeneous numeric file, some columns are text, etc.

You can get the numeric cols with :

```
a=np.genfromtxt('./desktop/alc.csv',delimiter=';',skip_header=1,usecols=(3,7,8,9,10))
```

But I think the best way for you here is to use pandas, better for such data:

```
df=pandas.read_csv('./desktop/alc.csv',sep=';')
```

and deal with it.

Comment: Made your recommended change & I get: ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'???'

Comment: difficult to say more. Is it possible ta have a link on sample data ?

Comment: Certainly, here you go: http://www.filedropper.com/recordedalcoholpercapitaconsumption19801999

Comment: It'a commercial link, can you try an other, please?

Comment: It asks me my phone number :( .

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have that problem when I tried to access the same from a different browser.

Comment: Any luck with the data file?